# How to insert time from time picker in zf2

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework2

I am new to zendframework2. I wanna to insert time from time picker. I did a lot of practice, but time picker is not displayed when clicking on form field for selecting time..

form:

```
$this->add(array(
         'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Time',
         'name' => 'departure_time',
         'attributes' => array( 
         'id'        => 'departure_time',    
         'required' => 'required', 
         'type'   => 'text',
         ), 
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Departure Time ',
         ),
     ));
```

view :

```
 echo $this->form()->openTag($form);  
 echo $this->formRow($form->get('departure_time'));  
 echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
 echo $this->form()->closeTag();

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$( ".departure_time" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
});
</script>
```

Is there need to call jquery function through onclick event from **form**.
Thanks in advance. Please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the wrong selector string into your jQuery function.

Since you have

```
'id'        => 'departure_time',
```

It should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
     $( "#departure_time" ).datepicker({
       dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
       changeMonth: true,
       changeYear: true
     });
   });
</script>
```

Or you need to add class of departure_time to your ZF2 form config

**** UPDATE ****

You can add a class the same way as an id, for your code it would be:

```
$this->add(array(
     'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Time',
     'name' => 'departure_time',
     'attributes' => array( 
         'class'        => 'departure_time',    
         'required' => 'required', 
         'type'   => 'text',
     ), 
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Departure Time ',
     ),
 ));
```

Comment: Brother, how I will add class of departure_time to ZF2 form config?